# Calculate area using double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

I'm trying to calculate the area defined by the following curves: $y=x^2, 4x=y^2, y=6$ using double integrals.

I'm wondering whether my solution is correct:

Area = $\int^{6}_{0}\int^{\sqrt{4x}}_{0}1dydx - \int^{6}_{0}\int^{x^2}_{0}1dydx$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ztvwh65pyj. Are you looking for the region thats looks like a triangle bounded above by y=6?

Comment: @Ty. Yes, I think so. The triangle upper-bounded by $y=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not correct.

First, you should compute the intersection points of the curves $y=x^2$ and $4x=y^2$, which are $(0,0)$ and $\left(\sqrt[3]4,2\sqrt[3]2\right)$. When $y\in\left[0,2\sqrt[3]2\right)$, the curve $y=x^2$ is to the right of the curve $4x=y^2$; after that, it is located to the left.

So, you should compute$$\int_0^{2\sqrt[3]2}\int_{y^2/4}^{\sqrt y}1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy+\int_{2\sqrt[3]2}^6\int^{y^2/4}_{\sqrt y}1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: Are you sure it's correct? I'm not sure about the first integral. As far as I understand, you are calculating the area of the following part: https://i.imgur.com/CqHJVPM.png but it should be just upper "triangle". Shoudn't it just be the second integral?

Comment: If you are sure that it's just the upper triangle, then you're right, of course. Do you want me to edit my answer?

Comment: Oh I see now. No, that's not necessary. Thanks. Just a quick question, considering only the triangle, is my solution mentioned in the post correct? Just want to know if I understand it correctly.

Comment: No. If it's only that upper triangle that you are interested in, how can those integrals begin at $0$?

Comment: My way of thinking about it was that I take this area: https://i.imgur.com/oPSqKjt.png and subtract this area: https://i.imgur.com/57IK5l4.png

Comment: The idea is correct, and your first integral corresponds to your first picture. But your second diagram does *not* correspond to the second picture. Below the intersection point of both curves, you are removing everything to the left of the red line, whereas you should remove only what's to the left of the blue one. I don't think that the problem can be solved without computing the points at which your curves intersect.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing a picture is helpful to set up the double integral properly.

It is not difficult the find out the coordinates of the points $A, B, C, D$ by solving relevant equations. Let's denote $A=(a_1,a_2)$, $B=(b_1,b_2)$, $C=(c_1,c_2)$ and $D=(d_1,d_2)$. Then one way to set up the double integral is
$$
\int_{b_1}^{c_1}\left(\int_{\sqrt{4x}}^{x^2}1\; dy\right)\;dx+
\int_{c_1}^{d_1}\left(\int_{\sqrt{4x}}^{6}1\; dy\right)\;dx\;.
$$

[image]

Comment: Can you explain, please, $\sqrt{x}$, as lower boundary in inner integrals?

Comment: @zkutch: thank you for identifying a typo! The lower boundary should come from the curve $4x=y^2$ ($y>0$) and thus it should be $\sqrt{4x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Second possible answer, additional to José Carlos Santos's one, is

$$\int_{ \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{4}}^{\sqrt{3}} \int_{\sqrt{4x}}^{x^{2}} dxdy + \int_{\sqrt{3}}^{9} \int_{\sqrt{4x}}^{6}dxdy $$

For your variant it should be

$$\int^{6}_{0}\int^{\frac{y^2}{4}}_{0}1dydx - \int^{2\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}_{0}\int^{\frac{y^2}{4}}_{0}1dydx - \int_{2\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}^{6} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}}dydx $$

But there is 4-"angle" figure in the left of 3-"angle", which is also bounded by 3 curves:
$$ \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{0} \int_{x^2}^{6} dxdy  + \int_{0}^{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{4}} \int_{\sqrt{4x}}^{6} dxdy + \int_{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{4}}^{\sqrt{3}} \int_{x^2}^{6} dxdy $$